# What is wrong with my attempted setting up of TightVNC as a service?

Tags: 18.04, vnc, tightvncserver

I have TightVNC installed and working on my Ubuntu 18.4 virtual server, following [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-18-04) guide.
It says to use nano and create a 'unit' file called `/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service`. It then specifies the contents of the file, and I have checked and double-checked, but when I try and start the service with:

```
systemctl start vncserver@1
```

I get an error that says:

```
Job for vncserver@1.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
```

Then I run:

```
systemctl status vncserver@1.service
```

and I get this output:

```
● vncserver@1.service - Start TightVNC server at startup
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/vncserver@.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-08-28 19:13:08 UTC; 12h ago

Aug 28 19:13:08 BradysApp systemd[1]: Starting Start TightVNC server at startup...
Aug 28 19:13:08 BradysApp vncserver[1232]: Can't find file /home/brady/.vnc/BradysApp:1.pid
Aug 28 19:13:08 BradysApp vncserver[1232]: You'll have to kill the Xtightvnc process manually
Aug 28 19:13:08 BradysApp systemd[1]: vncserver@1.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=2
Aug 28 19:13:08 BradysApp systemd[1]: vncserver@1.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 28 19:13:08 BradysApp systemd[1]: Failed to start Start TightVNC server at startup.
```

My unit file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Start TightVNC server at startup
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=brady
Group=brady
WorkingDirectory=/home/brady
PIDFile=/home/brady/.vnc/%H:%i.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i > /dev/null 2>&1
ExecStart=/usr/bin/vncserver -depth 24 -geometry 1280x800 :%i
ExecStop=/usr/bin/vncserver -kill :%i

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The user `brady` is my non-root user and works just fine, so that isn't the problem.

Any ideas or suggestions as to what might be wrong? I am a total Linux novice, working on a Digital Ocean VPS's web-based terminal.

Comment: It's best to post results as text, not screenshots. Also the lines in the screenshot are truncated. Suggest editing your question to include full results.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I don't know how to copy from the Ubuntu clipboard to the Windows one, even using TightVNC, and the truncation looks just like that in my terminal - there isn't more you I can see that you can't.

Comment: How about the error that says `can't find file /home/brady/.vnc/Bradysapp...`? It looks like that might be related to the PIDFile line in your unit file. The Bradysapp part looks suspicious.  What is %H supposed to represent?

Comment: My 'droplet' name is `Bradysapp` (host name), so I assume `%H` is some sort of macro for hostname. I have no idea what a PID File is or what it must look like, I assumed the vnc installation should have created it, but now at your prompt, it is indeed missing.

Comment: I checked all the unit files on my computers and none have the PIDFile line in them. I was hoping to find a working example, but I couldn't.  I'm going to spin up a virtual machine real quick and give it a try. Will report back.

Comment: OK, I ran through the tutorial and it worked for me with one exception. When I did `sudo systemctl status vncserver@1` near the end of Step 4, the service was not running. I got `Active: inactive (dead)`.  So I just issued a `sudo systemctl start vncserver@1.service` and then it worked.  I get the same error about the PIDFile not being found, so that is not the problem.  I'll keep the virtual machine around for a day or so in case you want to go some troubleshooting in chat. Ping me if you do.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I have a suspicion about that missing file. I created the user `brady` after I installed TightVNC, and I don't see a `.vnc` folder under `/home/brady/'. Doesn't VNC create this folder when it's installed? Then it would never have created one for `brady`.

Comment: Forgive me if you know this already, but you said you were new. Files that start with a . are hidden. To show them, use `ls -a` in the terminal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112426/discussion-between-profk-and-organic-marble).

Comment: I'm glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0):

Based on discussions in comments and chat, the issue was resolved by re-running the setup procedure after the addition of the user whose desktop was to be shared.

Answer (score 0):

The `Group` parameter should be set to the group in your system. It's not the same as your username in general. You may use `ll` (an alias for the `ls -l` command) to check what group should be set to.

`Group` should be set to `users` in the example below:

```
-rw-------  1 awen users    406 Sep 26 07:15 .Xauthority
-rw-r--r--  1 awen users   1600 Apr  9  2020 .Xdefaults
-rw-r--r--  1 awen users     80 Sep 23 10:22 .bash_aliases
-rw-------  1 awen users   8440 Sep 26 07:23 .bash_history
```